# Deploying and running my Python code on Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm really new at cloud stuff and I'd like to deploy and run my app in the cloud, so I chose Amazon Web Services (AWS).

My app or code function is to scrape webstites and store it in a database that will be created in AWS also.

My code is written in Python.

What my "system" supposed to do is:

- deploy and run my python code
- scrape websites
- store scraped data into a database
- database will be accessed by my android app to get the data

So far I've learned how to create an Amazon EC2 instance.

How will I go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a code in an Amazone's EC2 instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030115/how-to-run-a-code-in-an-amazones-ec2-instance)

Comment: You can instead try using AWS lambda, checkout here: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Comment: AWS Lambda probably isn't an optimal choice for scraping websites since execution will probably require more than 5 minutes. @boneyflesh: To reduce costs, remember to turn off your EC2 instance when it isn't required. Your app could simply shutdown the machine when it has finished a scraping run and you can Start it again later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to create an EC2 instance in AWS, that's the first step. When you create one make sure that you choose an OS or environment that you can handle. Running a python script that scrapes websites is not a very challenging task for a server, so you might want to chose a T2 micro in the beginning. It's [free](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) and you can try out things.

If you chose the AWS default AMI (Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type, you chose this on the first screen when you create an EC2 instance) python is already installed and you should be able to run your scripts.

As a database you probably use MySQL or PostgreSQL. You can either install these databases on your EC2 instance or use Amazon RDS for this. RDS is the AWS database service for relational databases. Just create the database of your needs and start it up. You then have to adjust your python scripts to write to RDS and that's it.

If you want to install your database on your EC2 instance, make sure that you use EBS (Elastic Block Storage) for the installation an attach it to your EC2 instance. If you don't do this, all your data will be lost each time you terminate your EC2 instance. EBS can be attached and detached to EC2 instances and the data won't be deleted if you terminate any EC2 instance attached to it. Good luck!

(Just a little hint from my side, when you start to try out AWS: check your billing status every once in a while. if you use the services as described above, there won't be much costs. but I always feel safer doing this after I once forgot to terminate a Redshift instance and went on holidays... ;-))

Comment: this is interesting i feel like i can achieve what i want with this. but umm i really dont know a thing about this topic so uhh how does this work? do i upload my code to my ec2 instance and it will run the code itself? (cuz thats what i hope it does)

Comment: yep, this is what you should do, @Boneyflesh

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Serverless Application Model would make all of this very easy for you.

This will give you a good start: [Introducing Simplified Serverless Application Deployment and Management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-simplified-serverless-application-deplyoment-and-management/)

This model will easily create Lambda functions (from your code), a database, and create the roles needed to give them access to each other. It's pretty sweet.