# error while running python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, python-requests

I am a learner of python.

i created one simple python script named as  test.py file location(/Users/AnbeswaranK/Desktop/python/test.py.

when i try to run the the script i am getting below error.

```
>>> python test.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 

>>> python /Users/AnbeswaranK/Desktop/python/test.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I have tried with location url  and without but unable to run.

can any one help me to understand, what i have to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you in the python interpreter by chance? (The prompt would suggest so). If so, run this command from the command line.

Comment: I am trying to run the via EC2 cli. here i dont know how to run the python script

Comment: Type simply `python` and hit enter and see where it takes you or does it give you any complain about doing so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a code in an Amazone's EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030115/how-to-run-a-code-in-an-amazones-ec2-instance)

Comment: >>> python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined

Comment: I am able to get into python. the only problem is unable to run python scripts

Comment: Thanks all. I can run the python script now. I came out from python and run with python script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your command prompt.
2. Navigate to the folder where your test.py is located.
3. type and enter: python test.py

Comment: i am not running in cmd prompt. try to run via AWS ec2 cli. here i dont know how to navigate the folder

Comment: Thanks all. I can run the python script now. I came out from python and run with python script.

Answer (score 0):

Check test.py and make sure you have only python command. 
I had the same as I saved from IDLE with all not necessary text coming by default with IDLE.
I.e.:

1. move test.py on your Desktop, erase everything inside it and replace with a simple command like : `print('Hallo')`
2. open Terminal , move to Desktop with `cd /Users/AnbeswaranK/Desktop`
3. write `python test.py`

When you want to create a new python file just click on "File-->New File" of the IDLE :-)

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I am seeing, primarily with ">>>python test.py" this tells me that the reason why you have an error is because you wrote it in the IDLE Shell and saved it. I just ran into this problem and figured it out.

So what you are going to want to do is this:

1. Open "File" and go to "New File"
2. Write you code in the new file.
3. Save your file in your desktop (you don't have to save it here, it can be anywhere).
4. Open your terminal and go to that path ( I like to go to the File Explorer, go to where my file is located and type in "cmd" so that the command prompt can open with path already there).
5. Type "python [yourfilename].py" and BOOM, you should be good to go.