# How to run python code on cloud

Tags: python, cloud

I have a python code which is quite heavy, my computer cant run it efficiently, therefore i want to run the python code on cloud.

Please tell me how to do it ? any step by step tutorial available

thanks

Comment: You can get so many answers by just googling your question. There are lots of cloud services including google cloud, amazon aws, microsoft azure and many others.

Comment: As pointed out above there are many services but Amazon's is easy to use, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030115/how-to-run-a-code-in-an-amazones-ec2-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience I would recommend Amazon Web Services: https://aws.amazon.com/.

I would suggest for you to look about creating an EC2 Instance and run your code there. An EC2 Instance basically is some kind of server and you can automate your Python script there as well.

Now, there's this tutorial that helped me a lot to have a clearer image about running Python script using AWS (specifically EC2): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE303yFWfV4.

For further informations about Cloud Services in Amazon and products, you can get informations here: https://aws.amazon.com/products/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Heroku. It's free and they got their own tutorials. But it's good enough only if you will use it for studying. AWS, Azure or google cloud are much better for production.